# using arc4random to generate random number to add to string for UI testing login xcode UI testing

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, xcode-ui-testing, arc4random

I am testing sign up on an app, using xcode UI testing i am wondering how to use the arc4random to generate a random number which will be typed into the app?

here is my code but getting a type cannont convert value of type UInt32 to expected argument type string.

```
 let emailBox = self.app.textFields["Email"]
    if emailBox.exists {enter code here
        emailBox.tap()
        emailBox.typeText("testing" + arc4random() + "gmail.com")
    }
```

Comment: "no subscript members error" means you should not use `[]` but `()`

Comment: Sorry, was old code. Updated now the error and brackets.

Comment: Use the `init(stringInterpolationSegment: UInt32)` constructor, i.e. `String(arc4random())` to make the `+` operator to work. You should read and try to understand the error message, which it tells you that it cannot be (automatically) converted to string. Secondly, completely changing the question content is not the correct SO way of doing so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
let emailBox = self.app.textFields["Email"]
if emailBox.exists {
    emailBox.tap()
    emailBox.typeText("testing" + String(arc4random()) + "gmail.com")
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfect

Comment: @SateNheehan if the answer worked, please mark it as "Correct" by hitting the check mark.

Answer (score 2):

you can just convert the integer generated by `arc4random()` to `String` like:

```
emailBox.typeText("testing\(String(arc4random()))gmail.com")
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution!